# Create large file using Convert.FromBase64String from a ntext column using Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am trying to create files from a `ntext` column I have stored in SQL Server 2008 R2 database. Once these files go over 14.5MB, the files truncate at this size.

Here is a screen shot of the filesystem after this has been performed.

[image: filesystem size]

And here is the data for the same file from the data table.

[image: database size]

The body column is stored base64 and I got the size using the `datalength` function.

I am using Entity Framework 6 for ADO to extract the data from the database. The stored procedure returns the column `Body`. Here is the code to call this and save the file:

```
// ****** Create the file ******
var bytes = db.stp_Get_SFDC_Doc_Body(a.Attach_Id);

foreach (string body in bytes)
{
    File.WriteAllBytes(fullPath, Convert.FromBase64String(body));
}
```

I have been browsing the internet for awhile and I can't see anything that would truncate the field. But if I inspect the body length it is always coming out to be: 19922944

It seems that either the `ntext` content is getting truncated by the stored procedure or by EF. I just can't seem to figure out which one it is.

I am using .NET 4.5 and I have set my project to use 64-Bit.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Gene

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Why do you save it in base64, and not just as binary? What length is the column defined as?

Answer (score -1):

Try using nvarchar(max).

It will not auto-truncate.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't auto-truncate anyway (unless configured to), so there is another problem here.

Comment: @Obihai - you should include more details in your answer, possibly examples, to show you are addressing the question at hand